# Framework for Implement Text Mining Pipeline with Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, pipeline, text-mining

I need to develop text document processing pipeline with several processing stages. So I'm looking for a good Java based framework to handle the pipeline with multithreaded processing as I want to focus more on business logic in each processing stage.

After searching few hours, I found following frameworks which goes with some of my requirements. But all of them have their own drawbacks

[Apache Commons Pipeline](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-pipeline/) - Seems this is not an active project anymore and doesn't have good documentation

[TinkerPop Pipes](https://github.com/tinkerpop/pipes/wiki) -  Doesn't support multithreaded execution

[Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) - Doesn't support several processing stages

Can anyone suggest me any other good lightweight framework for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [easy batch](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-batch). It allows you to easily develop pipelines with Java. It also supports parallelism. It was designed to address drawbacks of the frameworks you mentioned with a lightweight and easy to use alternative.

Hope it helps

Comment: hile this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for, even though we managed to write our own custom code for the purpose. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into UIMA (https://uima.apache.org/). IBM Watson uses it too.